# Dynamic query SQL where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to attach numeric value in dynamic query but I am an getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' + @psRegionCode + ' to data type smallint

My query is:

```
SET @psRegionCode = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@psRegionCode)))

IF (@psRegionCode <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sSQLStr = @sSQLStr + ' ' + 'AND reg.region_cd = ''' + @psRegionCode + ''''
END
```

Things which I tried:

```
SET @psRegionCode = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@psRegionCode)))
IF (@psRegionCode <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sSQLStr = @sSQLStr + ' ' +
        'AND reg.region_cd = ' + cast(@psRegionCode as nvarchar(10) ''
END
```

Can somone please help me with this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s i added additional tag sqlserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 IF (@psRegionCode <> 0)
 BEGIN
     SET @sSQLStr = @sSQLStr + 
         ' AND reg.region_cd = ' + cast(@psRegionCode as nvarchar(10))
```

1. you need to make sure you have correct number of apostrophes
2. if @psRegionCode is number, why you ltrim it? if it is a string why you cast it?

Comment: it was string previously

Comment: So now you don't need the first statement, if it is not a string. Is the dynamic sql working?

Comment: perhaps you will edit your question with more information about @sSQLStr?

Comment: Dear Liya , when i print  my Query it print like'' WHERE repStat.rep_state_flg = 'Y'  AND reg.region_cd = ' + @psRegionCode + '                                                    it shoud print WHERE repStat.rep_state_flg = 'Y'  AND reg.region_cd = 3

Comment: why after psRegionCode you still have + ' ? here is an example    (I skip variable sign @, becuase it doesn't let me put it here)                                   declare  psRegionCode smallint = 2
declare sSQLStr nvarchar(200) 
set sSQLStr = ''
     SET sSQLStr = sSQLStr + 
         ' AND reg.region_cd = ' + cast(psRegionCode as nvarchar(10))

select sSQLStr
It returns    AND reg.region_cd = 2

Answer (score 2):

Well, by your syntax I'm guessing SQL-Server? Any way I think your second query should work, you are just missing a parenthesis :

```
IF (@psRegionCode <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sSQLStr = @sSQLStr + 
        ' AND reg.region_cd = ' + cast(@psRegionCode as nvarchar(10)) 
END
```

You can't  concat a number into a string without the conversion.

Comment: there is a problem with '

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: What type is `@psRegionCode` ?

Comment: @sagi  I remove that first line upper lrtim an rtrim but still getting same error

Comment: when i print my Query it print like'' WHERE repStat.rep_state_flg = 'Y' AND reg.region_cd = ' + @psRegionCode + '                                          it shoud print WHERE repStat.rep_state_flg = 'Y' AND reg.region_cd = 3